# Animation of CSS Pseudo Element not working

Tags: css

I'm trying to spin the a pseudo element, however, while the animation works perfectly on other elements, the pseudo element doesn't move.

HTML:

```
<div class="spinning">
    some content
</div>
```

CSS:

```
@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(359deg);
  }
}

.spinning::before {
  content: 'x';
  animation: spin 2s infinite linear;
}
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7x0tasnh/

Applying the animation rule to the `div` works, with `::before` it doesn't work. What am I missing?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Add `display: inline-block` to your :before

```css
@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(359deg);
  }
}

.spinning::before {
  content: 'x';
  animation: spin 2s infinite linear;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="spinning"></div>
```

Comment: Wonderful, thanks for the blazingly fast answer (cannot accept yet, but I will). Would you mind explaining why that is? Non-block elements cannot be transformed, I assume?

Comment: @Tim-Erwin Yes.